# SharedPreferences error build iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I developed my application with Flutter on my main machine (Linux) and with Android everything works fine.

I tried to build my code on a Mac machine for iOS but I receive an error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           15,6s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer
/Users/andreacocci/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/shared_preferences_foundation-2.3.0/darwin/Classes/SharedPreferencesPlugin.swift:57:21
SharedPreferencesPlugin.swift:57

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Exited (1).
```

What can I do?

I have already tried deleting Podfile.lock and Pod folder and run again pod install but not works.

Some info:

- shared_preferences version 2.2.0
- Flutter sdk version 3.10.5
- Xcode version 14.3.1
- MacOS version 13.4.1
- Flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 13.4.1 22F82 darwin-x64, locale it-IT)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands.

'flutter clean'

'flutter pub get'

'flutter run'

If above commands doesn't work then trying removing 'Podfile.lock' from iOS folder and do 'Pod install' again.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Delete your pod file.lock and pod reintegrate pod setup pod install

Most of the time ios issues are related to podfile.

Did your pod install worked fine previously?